# Span tooltip position remains fixed when i slide the image to another position and hover over it

Tags: html, css, image, hover, tooltip

I have an image container with images and text below it.
Since the title of image is long, i used text-overflow property to hide long text and used a tooltip for displaying the long text of title when i hover over the title. This thing is working fine. see here:
[[image: tooltip shown when i hover over the title][1]]

But issue i am facing here is this is an image slider and when i slide the image and hover over the image, the tooltip still remains fixed in same position for each image and it seems like its shown for another image. Basically I want the tooltip to be relative to the same image. See here i scrolled left and hovered over first title and it shows under second title hoover[image]

Basically i want the hover to be relative to the title when scrolled. I tried adding position:relative in tooltiptext but the boxes were disrupted like this:[image]

Please can someone help me fix this? I want the title to be visible when hovered as image1 but when i scroll it should move along with he image.

HTML code:

```
                        <div className="image-container">
                            <center>
                                <div className='container p-1'>
                                    <div className="image">
                                        <img style={{ width: 200, height: 200 }} src="http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/51PhUckHB3L.jpg"></img>
                                        <div className="caption">Product Title<br></br>
                                            <small className='ellipsis'>Electrolux EENB54EB Ultraenergica Classic Aspirapolvere</small>
                                            <span className="tooltiptext">Electrolux EENB54EB Ultraenergica Classic Aspirapolvere</span> 
                                           
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                     
                                    
                                </div>
                                <div className='container p-1'>
                                    <div className="image">
                                        <img style={{ width: 200, height: 200 }} src="http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/518Se4188mL.jpg"></img>
                                        <div className="caption">Left Product Title<br></br>
                                        <small className='ellipsis'>Amore Legno Sforza segnalibro, segnalibro particolare, segnalibro legno, segnalibro laurea, idea regalo, segnalibri regali, regali originali per amiche, portafortuna da regalare, made in Italy</small>
                                        <span className="tooltiptext">Amore Legno Sforza segnalibro, segnalibro particolare, segnalibro legno, segnalibro laurea, idea regalo, segnalibri regali, regali originali per amiche, portafortuna da regalare, made in Italy</span>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    
                                </div>
                                <div className='container p-1'>
                                    <div className="image">
                                        <img style={{ width: 200, height: 200 }} src="http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/518Se4188mL.jpg"></img>
                                        <div className="caption">Right Product Title<br></br>
                                        <small className='ellipsis'>Amore Legno Sforza segnalibro, segnalibro particolare, segnalibro legno, segnalibro laurea, idea regalo, segnalibri regali, regali originali per amiche, portafortuna da regalare, made in Italy</small>
                                        <span className="tooltiptext">Third Legno Sforza segnalibro, segnalibro particolare, segnalibro legno, segnalibro laurea, idea regalo, segnalibri regali, regali originali per amiche, portafortuna da regalare, made in Italy</span>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    
                                </div>
                            
                                
                            </center>
                        </div>
```

CSS code:

```
.container {
   margin: 10px;
   display: inline-block; 
   justify-content: center;
   width: 50%;
   flex-direction: column;
   border: 1px solid black;
 }

.caption{
  justify-content: center;
  border-top: 1px solid black;
}

.image{
  width: 100%;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
 
.image-container {
   vertical-align: middle;
   display: inline-block;
   white-space: nowrap;
   /* overflow-x: auto; */
   overflow-y: hidden;
   width: 100%;
 }
 
.details{
  background-color: white;
  position: relative;
  overflow: scroll;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 100vh;
}

.ellipsis {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
  padding:.5rem 1rem;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.ellipsis:focus .ellipsis:hover{
color: red;
}

.box{
border-top: 1px solid black;
}

.tooltiptext{
  position: relative; 
  /* top:105%; */
  /* left:0%; */
  /* right: 0; */
  z-index: 1;
  /*op: 105%;
  left: 0%;*/

  transform: translateY(0%); 
 
  background-color: #000;
  border-radius: 7px;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 15px;
  line-height: 20px;
  /*padding: 10px 5px;*/

  display: block;
  width: 200px;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  white-space: normal;
  text-align: center;

  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 0.5s ease;

  overflow: scroll;
}

.ellipsis:hover+.tooltiptext{
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

**Update**
Update after Anil Kumar's suggestion in comment of adding { position: relative;} in image container. The tooltip moves with scroll but is still getting hidden. See image:
[image]
Think we are close, need help

Comment: `.image-container{ position: relative;}` and `.tooltiptext{position: absolute;}` . Update this

Comment: In HTML5 the 'center' tag is [no longer valid](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_center.asp)

Comment: @Anilkumar thanks after this it is relative but the text is getting hidden. Let me update the original question to show you the behavior

Comment: @Anilkumar I added the image below after your suggestion. Please can you check and advise? Why is the text getting hidden still?

Comment: @Anilkumar I also added z-index: 1; and z-index: 2;in tooltiptext but still same

Answer (score 1):

I have tried to update your code with few html and css changes. Check will this work for you.

```css
.image-container {
  overflow-y: hidden;
  width: 100%;
}

.wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.container {
  margin: 10px;
  width: 33%;
  border: 1px solid black;
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.caption {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  border-top: 1px solid black;
 
}

.image{
  position: relative;
}

img {
  position: relative;
}

.ellipsis {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  padding: .5rem 1rem;
}

.tooltiptext {
  visibility: hidden;
  display: none;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 0.5s ease;
}

.ellipsis:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.ellipsis:hover+.tooltiptext {
  visibility: visible;
  display: block;
  opacity: 1;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: #000;
  border-radius: 7px;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 15px;
  line-height: 20px;
  width: 90%;
  padding: 10px;
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="image-container">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class='container p-1'>
      <div class="image">
        <img style='width: 100%; height: 200px;' src="http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/518Se4188mL.jpg">
        <div class="caption">Product Title</div>
        <small class='ellipsis'>Electrolux EENB54EB Ultraenergica Classic Aspirapolvere</small>
        <span class="tooltiptext">Electrolux EENB54EB Ultraenergica Classic Aspirapolvere</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class='container p-1'>
      <div class="image">
        <img style='width: 100%; height: 200px;' src="http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/518Se4188mL.jpg">
        <div class="caption">Left Product Title</div>
        <small class='ellipsis'>Amore Legno Sforza segnalibro, segnalibro particolare, segnalibro legno, segnalibro laurea, idea regalo, segnalibri regali, regali originali per amiche, portafortuna da regalare, made in Italy</small>
        <span class="tooltiptext">Amore Legno Sforza segnalibro, segnalibro particolare, segnalibro legno, segnalibro laurea, idea regalo, segnalibri regali, regali originali per amiche, portafortuna da regalare, made in Italy</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class='container p-1'>
      <div class="image">
        <img style='width: 100%; height: 200px;' src="http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/518Se4188mL.jpg">
        <div class="caption">Right Product Title</div>
        <small class='ellipsis'>Amore Legno Sforza segnalibro, segnalibro particolare, segnalibro legno, segnalibro laurea, idea regalo, segnalibri regali, regali originali per amiche, portafortuna da regalare, made in Italy</small>
        <span class="tooltiptext">Third Legno Sforza segnalibro, segnalibro particolare, segnalibro legno, segnalibro laurea, idea regalo, segnalibri regali, regali originali per amiche, portafortuna da regalare, made in Italy</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```